# The Student's List Won't Added Using React JS Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

It supposed to add the student list when I click on the button, but it doesn't.
[image: the problem]

**It should be like the pict below:**
[image]

I already check my code, and here it is:

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";
import Operation from "antd/lib/transfer/operation";
import { PlusCircleOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

function App() {
  
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Dynamic Form Dengan Validasi</h2>
       <form>
        <Form.Item name={"teacher"} label="Teacher Name">
          <Input placeholder="Teacher Name"></Input>
        </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name={"class"} label="Class Name">
          <Input placeholder="Class"></Input>
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.List name={"students"}>
          {(fields, {add, remove}) => (
            <>
              {fields.map((field, index)=>{
                return (
                  <Form.Item name={[field.name,"first"]} label={`${index + 1}-Student`}>
          <Input placeholder="First Name"></Input>
        </Form.Item>
                );
              })}
              <Form.Item>
                <Button icon={<PlusCircleOutlined />} type="dashed" block onClick={() => { add();}}>
                 Add A Student</Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </>
          )}
        </Form.List>
       </form>
      
      
      </div>
  );
  
}

export default App;
```

I don't know what went wrong, only see the warning in the first pict.

Comment: 1. when you create a form, it prefers to use with onSubmited and
2. you need to use useState to save the inputs

Comment: What does add function do ? Need more clear info

Comment: to add the student list like the secong pict

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `Form.Provider`. You need it in order to use `Form`

```
import { FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form';
```

After that make sure to wrap your `<Form>` tag with a `<FormProvider>` tag.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Dynamic Form Dengan Validasi</h2>
      <FormProvider>
        <Form>
          <Form.Item name={"teacher"} label="Teacher Name">
            <Input placeholder="Teacher Name"></Input>
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name={"class"} label="Class Name">
            <Input placeholder="Class"></Input>
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.List name={"students"}>
            {(fields, {add, remove}) => (
              <>
                {fields.map((field, index)=>{
                  return (
                    <Form.Item name={[field.name,"first"]} label={`${index + 1}-Student`}>
                      <Input placeholder="First Name"></Input>
                    </Form.Item>
                  );
                })}
                <Form.Item>
                  <Button icon={<PlusCircleOutlined />} type="dashed" block onClick={() => { add();}}>
                    Add A Student
                  </Button>
                </Form.Item>
              </>
            )}
          </Form.List>
        </Form>
      </FormProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it gives me "port 'FormProvider' (imported as 'FormProvider') was not found in 'antd'"

Comment: I'm sorry, I messed up the library, it belongs to react-hook-form.
Use import { FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form'; instead.
I'll edit my answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: it gives me this "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-hook-form' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Latihan React JS\dinamik form crud dng validasi pake ant design\src"

Comment: You need to install it ... npm install react-hook-form

Comment: it does not change anything

Comment: Does it work if you add `import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';` ?

Comment: it still remains the same actually